# Maintain the dynamic CSS on switching tabs on page and on reload

Tags: javascript, css

In my application, there is an option for the user to change the CSS of the page on click of a button. I want that the selected style should remain if the user visits another link on the page or if the page is reloaded, i.e. the user should not have to select the style/theme of choice again and again.

How can I achieve this ?

```css
function switch_style (style){
 
    if(theme == "blue"){
        document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:blue');
    }
    else if(theme == "black"){
        document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:black');
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="switch_style('blue') id="blue">Blue</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="switch_style('black')id="black">Black</button>
     <p id="test">SAMPLE TEXT</p>
```

Comment: you can use javascript localstorage or cookies to save this property on the client side and load it from there if exists, otherwise set it to default.

Comment: @AniketKariya is right. As he said you have to use `localStorage` for implement logic. Added solutions.

Comment: Notice you are missing the closing quite (`"`) on the `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For storing value you need to add `localStorage` from browser.
Here is details about it : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Sample code you can use this :

```
function switch_style (style)
{

if(theme == "blue"){
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:blue');
}
else if(theme == "black"){
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:black');
}
localStorage.setItem("style_theme", theme);

}
```

and onload check for `localstorage`

```
var style_theme = localStorage.getItem("style_theme");
if(!style_theme){
style_theme = "blue" // set default theme which want to.
}
switch_style(style_theme);
```

Based on this you can call function.

Answer (score 3):

Using Local Storage:

// tweaking s**witch_style** to use local storage

```
function switch_style (theme) {
  // making switch_style update local staorage any time page theme is changed

  localStorage.setItem('currentThemeColor', theme);

  if(theme == "blue"){
  document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:blue');
  
  
  } else if (theme == "black") {
      document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('style','color:black');
 
  }

}

// for every page add an eventLister that runs after the page load to get the currentThemeColor from localStorage and apply it ont the current page...
// Example:

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // getting currentThemeColor from localStorage;
  const currentThemeColor = localStorage.getItem('currentThemeColor') || "blue"; // setting blue as fallball color if localStorage has no currentThemeColor
  
  // updating page theme
  switch_style(currentThemeColor);
})
```

Comment: This is also right. Upvoted. Small correction you move `setItem` out side if else block avoid repeating of code. @Rilla

Comment: Thank you sharing the solution ! :)